# Putting hyphen in the title of a webpage

Tags: html

I want to put a hyphen in the title of a webpage like

```
<head><title>Project Name - Module Name</head></title>
```

however I am getting this question mark in all browsers.
[image]

How can I put the hyphen?

Comment: I can use _ than -. Submitted this question here for some discussion and input.

Comment: Try adding this to your page.. <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> Or simply HTML5 version <meta charset="utf-8" />

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: Anyone explain the seemingly random down votes?

Comment: Can any1 explain me what's wrong in my answer?

Comment: someone's playing foul out here, randomly down voting the answers without any actual reason to do so..

Comment: I seem to have escaped the downvotes, no idea why. I have upvoted you guys, both good answers

Comment: @codebox haha lucky you..n thanx bro, but upvotes downvotes really doesn't matter but here it was nothing wrong so I felt that something is really wrong with my answer ;)

Comment: This was already there still the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the 'hyphen' character you have inserted isn't a true hyphen (ASCII code 45) but one of the characters that look similar. Did you paste the title from MSWord by any chance? Try typing a hyphen in a text editor (eg Notepad) and copy/pasting it into your HTML source.

For a working example of a page with a hyphen in the title, look at this page.

Comment: The code fragment in the question contains Ascii hyphen (hyphen-minus, U+002D, decimal code 45), but it is possible that the fragment was not copypasted (or the copypaste changed something).

Comment: @codebox: You caught it right! :) I was using notepad++ to edit html and so the problem. Edited with notepad and it works fine.

Comment: @veer7 could you elaborate? I used Notepad++ and it worked just fine. I can guarantee you one thing is that when you type a hyphen into Notepad++ you get a hypen.

Comment: @Celertas: Notepad++ gives - for typying hyphen. That hyphen was brought into code from outlook mail. You are right.

Answer (score 3):

The symbol that looks like a white question mark in a lozenge is REPLACEMENT CHARACTER, indicating character-level data error: the data contains a byte or sequence of bytes that does not represent any character in the character encoding being applied. For example, a windows-1252 encoded en dash “–” in data declared as being UTF-8 encoded.

The real solution is to fix the encoding mismatch, but this requires more information about the situation.

A quick fix is to change the character (which is probably “–”) to `&ndash;`, which works independently of character encoding. Changing it to a hyphen “-” would be an improvement to the current situation, but English punctuation rules make a distinction between the hyphen and the en dash: a hyphen never appears as isolated, with spaces around.

Answer (score 1):

Did you actually type in a hyphen to the source code? That seems to happen when you copy and paste from a program like Word or Outlook. Also try replacing the dash with one of the entities (from shortest to longest) `&#45;`, `&#150;` or `&#151;` though the first really is just a dash. Refer to [here](http://www.nationalfinder.com/html/char-asc.htm) for more info.

What text editor are you using? It may be causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use

**&#45;**

This is the HTML code for hyphen

like this

```
<title>Project Name &#45; Module Name</head></title>
```

You can get more codes from [here](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) if you want

Comment: There is no reason to use `&#45;` (still less the sloppy `&#45`) in HTML: it simply stands for the hyphen “-”. So if the change helped, then the character was *not* a hyphen.

Comment: Actually using HTML codes to render special characters is a good habit as W3C also validate these characters.

Comment: @yogi yes but just typing - validates as well. What's your point? Or were you not replying directly to Jukka K. Korpela?

Comment: Yeah that was for Jukka, Its just matter of maintaining a good habit when you are coding using these character code seems ugly I accept.

Comment: @yogi, the hyphen is hardly a special character, and the modern way is to enter even special characters as such when possible, using UTF-8, as it helps to avoid errors with the code. The W3C recommends avoiding “character escapes”: http://www.w3.org/International/techniques/authoring-html#escapes